# Include Mapstruct context into internal mappers

Tags: spring, mapstruct

I'm using MapStruct 1.3.0.Final to convert Dtos into POJOs and vice versa with the **spring** value into *mapstruct.defaultComponentModel* option. To avoid  stackoverflow errors due to bidirectional relations I have followed the next link:

[Mapping With Cycles](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles)

However, the compilation phase (to generate the implementations) is taking a lot of time (with only 20 files around 15 minutes and I need to include more ones).

I cannot "reuse" existing mappers due to I cannot "send" then the context using:

```
@Mapper(uses=B_Mapper.class)
A_Mapper ...
```

So, is there an optimization option to reduce the amount of time required? Is there a way to pass the context into the "internal mappers" (in the above example *B_Mapper*)?

**UPDATE**

That is the skeleton of the application:

```
public class EntityA {
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="entityA")
  private List<EntityB> entitiesB;
  ...
}

public class EntityB {
  ...
  @ManyToOne
  private EntityA entityA;
  ...
}
```

DTO:

```
public class DtoA { 
  ...
  private List<DtoB> dtosB;
  ...
}

public class DtoB { 
  ...
  private DtoA dtoA;
  ...
}
```

There are many more "columns and bidirectional relations" in several entities/dtos.

Converter:

```
public interface BaseConverter<D, E> {

  E fromDtoToEntity(final D dto, @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext context);

  // This is the method I really use for the conversions
  @Named("originalFromDtoToEntity")
  default E fromDtoToEntity(final D dto) {
    return fromDtoToEntity(dto, new CycleAvoidingMappingContext());
  }
  ...
}

@Mapper
public interface AConverter extends BaseConverter<DtoA, EntityA>{}

@Mapper
public interface BConverter extends BaseConverter<DtoB, EntityB>{}
```

Comment: 15 minutes is really slow. Is it possible to provide us with a minimal example demonstrating this problem, maybe we can find the underlying problem.

Comment: Hi Filip, we have to deal with an "old database", with tables with 30-40 columns, several of them FK to other ones. A big percentage of those relations have to be mapped with JPA/Hibernate as bidirectional relations, avoiding performance problems of that technology.

Comment: What I meant is about the compilation time, it shouldn't take 15 minutes, no matter how complex your application is. For the `B_Mapper` you can use `@Context` in it and it'll get passed to it.

Comment: I have updated the question with the skeleton of the converters. Can you explain me how I can pass the `@Context` between converters you are talking about?

Comment: Tried to answer it. In theory you don't need to do anything, just call the appropriate method, MapStruct will do the same. For the performance, are you sure that only those converters take long time? I can investigate that separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your converters it means that the `CycleAvoidingContext` is already passed if you use them. For example:

```
@Mapper(uses = BConverter.class, componentModel = "spring")
public interface AConverter extends BaseConverter<DtoA, EntityA>{}

@Mapper(uses = AConverter.class, componentModel = "spring")
public interface BConverter extends BaseConverter<DtoB, EntityB>{}
```

Then when invoking it MapStruct will correctly invoke `fromDtoToEntity` and pass the `CycleAvoidingContext` there.

Keep in mind the `spring` `componentModel`, the default cannot be used due to the cyclic dependency between the mappers.

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm. I was using the "spring option" in the `pom.xml` file instead of in the `@Mapper`

Comment: Using the spring option in the pom should also work. Only problem could be in an IDE in case the option was not properly picked